# argument of type * is incompatible with parameter of type "const float *"

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm fairly new to C++. I've searched extensively but I couldn't make it work.

I've defined a custom type called `vec_t`:

```cpp
class FloatType {
    private:
        float value;
    public:
        FloatType() : value(0.0f) {}
        FloatType(float v) : value(v) {}

        //operator float() { return value; }
        //operator float() { return value; }
        //explicit operator const float* () { return &value; }
        //operator float* () const { return &value; }
        //operator const float* () { return &value; }
        //operator const float() { return (const float)value; }
        //operator const float*() { return &value; }
};

typedef FloatType vec_t;
```

I've also created a function which takes a `const float *` as its only argument:

```cpp
void Create(const float* vColor = NULL);

void Create(const float* vColor) {
    //...
}
```

Now, when calling the function like so:

```cpp
vec_t a = { 2.5f };
vec_t* b = &a;
Create(b);
```

Visual Studio Community 2019 (v142) is complaining:

> argument of type "vec_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const float *"

Now, casting it to `const float *` on the spot gets it done:

```cpp
Create((const float *)b);
```

But, my goal is to have an implicit casting operator to implicitly convert from my type to `const float *`, but no matter my efforts, I can not seem to have it right.

All `operator` comments were my attempts and they all have valid syntax, but they don't make the problem go away.

What am I not understanding?

I want to be able to handle this from within the `FloatType` class itself, and to my knowledge, an implicit casting operator is the way to do so.

Don't guide me to another approach, this is purely for practice and exercise.

Comment: Pass `a` instead of `b` and your operators will work.

Comment: "_Now, casting it to "const float *" on the spot gets it done:_": No, this causes undefined behavior. It only seems to work. Don't use C style casts like this in C++. You will end up causing undefined behavior like you do here.

Comment: Actually, it turns out in this very specific case your cast is valid. (Your class happens to be standard-layout.) What I said does however apply in general.

Comment: The real question is, why is `Create()` taking a `float` by pointer in the first place, instead of taking it by value?

Comment: *my goal is to have an implicit casting operator to implicitly convert from my type to const float \** Looks like a *very* bad idea to me. Implicit conversions are a problem rather than a solution, and pointers don't seem to be needed here at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `vec_t` type is not a pointer, so you should not be using a pointer as the argument when calling `Create()`:

```
class FloatType 
{
private:
    float value;
public:
    ...
    operator const float* () const { return &value; }
               // const here ^^^^^
};

typedef FloatType vec_t;

vec_t a = { 2.5f };
Create(a);
```

For some reason, you introduced the pointer `b`, that's the main reason your code doesn't work.

Also, you should have an extra `const` on your conversion operator, as I've indicated above.

Comment: @user17732522 Obviously it is not. But I think it's best to answer the questions asked. The OP will learn about good design when they are ready.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while `vec_t` is a class type that can have conversion operators defined, `vec_t *` is a primitive type (a pointer), and no user-defined conversions apply to it.

Some possible solutions:

- Don't pass around pointers to `vec_t`, pass them by value instead. If necessary, use `std::move` to avoid potentially expensive copies. This boils down to just `Create(a)`. john's answer explains this in more detail.
- Dereference the pointer, as in `Create(*b)`, to allow the compiler to find your user-defined conversions.
- Add a `float * data()` member function to `vec_t`, just like `std::vector`, and call that to get at the underlying data: `Create(b->data())`
- **Don't use your own vector type** and just use `std::array<float, N>` for statically-sized vectors and `std::vector<float>` for dynamically sized ones. **This is likely the best solution.** To get a pointer to the raw data, use `vec.data()`. (Again, take advantage of these types' value semantics to get memory safety. Move / copy them, don't use raw pointers.)
- If you want something really ugly that you shouldn't do: `Create(b->operator float *())`.